# How to heat water at very high temepratures?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, evaporation, heat-engine

I am working on a project and recently came through a situation where I'll be working with water evaporation. On searching the internet I found that water heated at 350Celsius would generate almost 1600 newton force. But I'm confused that how will I be able to achieve 350 degree heat? I mean, the water itself evaporates at 100 degree, so how will I be able to hold it upto till 350 degree? or is there any other theory/way which I'm missing.

Comment: You heat it [under pressure](http://static.queenonline.com.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/11_Under_Pressure_30secs_1.mp3), ding ding ding ba-ba ding-ding.

Comment: "ding ding ding ba-ba ding-ding" does it mean that will explode? o.O

Comment: No, listen carefully to the scat backing in the song towards the end of @rob's link. Dunno whether it's Mercury or Bowie singing them, though.

Comment: A bit of a quibble with your question: newtons are a measure of force rather than pressure (force per unit area). At a given temperature (and volume) water/steam will have a certain pressure.  The force that it exerts depends on the size of the surface over which that pressure is applied.

Comment: I was actually thinking of the guitar line that opens the song, the one plagiarized in "Ice, Ice Baby" for what I assume must have been thermodynamic reasons

Comment: @rob: [It's not the same bass-line](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-1_9-z9rbY) ;)

Comment: I've no idea about what you guys are talking :P

Comment: @user3823992 Actually I've converted the "pressure due to vapor" into the unit of Force because afterall, I require only the force of the vapor. I hope this makes you understand ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of a pressure cooker...

The higher the pressure, the higher the boiling temperature. You need a vessel that will hold the pressure at 350C.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor_pressure#Boiling_point_of_water) gives a formula for the pressure need to get the boiling temperature of water up to a certain value. The formula is
$$T_b=1730.53/(8.07131-\log_{10}P) -233.426$$
where $T_b$ is the boiling temperature in C, and $P$ is the required pressure in Torr.

Putting 350 in the equation gives approximately $2\times10^5\,\rm Torr$ or $260\,\rm Atm$ or $26\,\rm MPa$.

Now build a pressure cooker strong enough to hold that (plus some safety margin I hope).

Comment: +1 Good answer. Your estimated pressure requirements are a teeny bit high. You're using the Antoine equation, which becomes very approximate at high temperatures. The graph on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapour_pressure_of_water tells me that $22{\rm MPa}$ will get me to the critical point at $647{\rm K}$ for water.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance is right on here.  Approximate equations are ok as a first attempt, but you're better off with empirical data if you need an exact answer. Fortunately, the properties of water/steam have been recorded in great detail (search for "steam table").

Comment: Point taken. I did say the result is approximate. Also, being on the high side gives an added safety factor.

Comment: Is it possible to build a pressure cooker which can survive 26MPa (any hint would be just great)? and I may be wrong  but would this create the pressure? I'm doubtful because my teacher told me that I would need to consider a cylindrical container and would require a piston to forcefully push the water inside while also heating it and then only I can get the force from the water vapor. He may be wrong, but would your pressure cooker idea would allow me to get the force from vapor? Thanks again for helping.

Comment: Sure it's possible to build a vessel that will take that pressure. I've read somewhere that a car engine with 11:1 compression has about 12 MPa at peak compression. So you need something strong enough to hold at least twice that pressure. Just don't ask me how! And, a petrol engine is used to get work done from the compression, so yes it could be done